# Filter with Combining and Negating Conditions with AND, OR, and NOT in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, where-clause

I want to filter the table based on some combination of conditions. Please refer the below code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #New
WHERE (
          (
              ClientSource_No <> 283
              AND Suppress_Fg <> 1
          )
          OR
          (
              ClientSource_No <> 289
              AND Suppress_Fg <> 1
          )
      );


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #New
WHERE (
          (
              ClientSource_No <> 283
              OR ClientSource_No <> 289
          )
          AND Suppress_Fg <> 1
      );
```

I tried to filter the table 2 different ways. I want filter the table based on 2 conditions

1. when `ClientSource_No = 283 and Suppress_Fg = 1` then exclude the record
2. when `ClientSource_No = 289 and Suppress_Fg = 1` then exclude the record.

When I execute above query it filtered out all records who has `Suppress_Fg = 1`.

I don't want to do self join the table or use `NOT EXITS` and exclude those records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way to express the conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #New
WHERE NOT ( ClientSource_No IN (283, 289) AND Suppress_Fg = 1 )
```

Or as:

```
WHERE lientSource_No NOT IN (283, 289) OR Suppress_Fg <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could phrase this as a `not` condition, like:

```
where not (ClientSource_No in (283, 289) and Suppress_Fg = 1)
```

On the other hand, the logic you wanted to use required `or` conditions rather than `and`:

```
where ClientSource_No not in (283, 289) or Suppress_Fg <> 1
```